# Design of Parks-McClellan Lowpass Filter

Tags: filter-design, lowpass-filter, finite-impulse-response, digital-filters

Can we design Parks-McClellan Lowpass Filter with only sampling frequency of 12KHz and cutoff frequency of 4KHz and order of 30? I went through Matlab help, where we need parameter like passband cutoff frquency, stopband cutoff frequency, passband ripple e.t.c.,

Comment: well, you'll get something.  but with only 31 taps, it won't be the most impressive FIR filter.

Comment: If so how can I construct it using firpm?

Comment: [is the MATLAB page not helpful](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/firpm.html)?

Answer (score 1):

The minimal specification for a FIR lowpass filter designed by the Parks McClellan algorithm is the passband edge, the stopband edge, and the filter order. You don't need to specify passband and stopband ripples; they are the result of the design process. What you *can* do is specify passband and stopband error weights, which let you specify the relation between passband and stopband approximation errors (a larger weight reduces the error).